# how to make a div and its inner content responsive

Tags: html, css

I am working on the project in which i have a div inside which i have 4 div. 
the inner div have fixed position 
i want to make the div responsive and along with that i want all the 4 div to retain their original position 
 here is my code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kahjww6/)

i have place the inner div position using margin-top , margin-left

```
.one{
    margin-top: 16em;
    margin-left: 2em;
    position: absolute;
}
.spinner.two {
    margin-top: 20em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    position: absolute;
}
.spinner.three {
    margin-left: 4em;
    margin-top: 23em;
    position: absolute;
}
.spinner.four {
     margin-left: 14em;
    margin-top: 19em;
    position: absolute;
}
```

but i does not make responsive.... please help

Comment: I do not know much about responsiveness but as a general rule you must specify in the CSS rules related to the size of the screen..you have to set up media rules along with their breakpoints....breakpoints the limits(in pixels) where the pixel dimensions must change to accommodate the various devices

Comment: In my experience, you should allow as many divs as possible to flow in a content-driven way. The height naturally increasing with narrower widths. Absolute positioning does not lend itself to this. I think a good responsive design doesn't necessarily require lots of media queries..

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle that is more responsive according to device width.
https://jsfiddle.net/0kahjww6/1/

```
.one { margin-left: 7%; }
.two { margin-left: 4%; }
.three { margin-left: 17%; }
.four { margin-left: 40%; }
```

The main things I changed were:

1. Removed absolute positionings where it wasn't necessary
2. Set width of active area to 100% of its container - the maximum width available, which responds to changes in browser width
3. Positioned things relatively inside this according to % width, rather than in terms of absolute pixels or ems

It may not be perfect for what you want, but it is certainly more responsive.